# React navigation navigating back using stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm on page_a and navigating to page_b, which is a part of a stack navigator. If I click to go back when on page_b, I expect to go back to page_a.

```
this.props.navigation.goBack()
```

Instead I am taken to add_to_report, which is the top item within my stack navigator.

```
const InspectionsNav = StackNavigator({
  add_to_report: {
    screen: AddToReport,
  }, 
  page_b: {
    screen: Confirm,
  }, 
  details_index: {
    screen: DetailTabs,
  }, 
  information: {
    screen: Information,
  }, 
})
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: try navigation.pop()

Comment: Just to confirm: Your screen stack is just Page_A -> Page_B. And when using goBack(), you ended up in Add_To_Report. Is there anywhere that actually cause that screen to be added to the stack in the first place?